# Prevent auto semicolon in Visual Studio Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I'm using the Visual Studio Code. I never want auto semicolon after CSS properties. But VS Code gives me an auto-complete option which I don't like.

How can I stop auto-complete semicolon at the end of CSS properties?

Answer (score 8):

1. Settings > Extensions > CSS , uncheck the Complete Property With Semicolon.

or

2. You can change the default values in the Settings editor.

search the code & change it from true to false.

```
// Insert semicolon at end of line when completing CSS properties
  "scss.completion.completePropertyWithSemicolon": false,
```

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 5):

1. Press Control + Shift + P in VSCode.
2. Search For  `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`.
3. Again in the Searchbar, search for `Semicolon`.
4. Choose CSS or your preferred language from where you want to remove auto
   semicolon.
5. Untick `Insert semicolon at the end of line when completing CSS properties`.

And you are done.

Answer (score 2):

In `Settings` go to `Extensions` -> `CSS` and uncheck 'Completion: Complete Property With Semicolon'

Answer (score 0):

Adding .prettierrc file in project root worked for me with following settings:

```
{
     "files": [
              "**/*.css"
              ],
     "options": {
                "semi": false,
                "parser": "css"
                }
}
```