# Prevent autocomplete semicolon in JavaScript VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm using the Visual Studio Code. I never want autocomplete functions with semicolon in JS.
Like when I type `log + TAB`, it appears `console.log();` with semicolon at the end.

How can I stop auto-complete semicolon at the end of JS functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539082/prevent-auto-semicolon-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: I need to remove semicolon at the end in JavaScript, not in SCSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make VSCode insert `console.log({})` instead of `console.log({});` when you type `log` and then press <kbd>tab</kbd>, you need to edit the snippet's body.

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> and type `snippets`
2. Select `Preferences: Configure User Snippets`
3. Select `console.log().code-snippets`
4. Change line 23 from `"console.log({$0});"` to `"console.log({$0})"`

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Preferences` of VSCode and search the `semicolons`. Then select `ignore` option.
[image]

Comment: I need to remove semicolons from autocomplete, not with formating..

Comment: Never imagined enforcing automatic semicolons would give me a little buzz.

Answer (score 0):

For visual studio 1.85.1 I found there are two ways to do this. One is to install a package that has a set of snippets without semicolons. I would recommend [this one](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jmsv.JavaScriptSnippetsStandard&ssr=false#overview).

The second way is to go to the default snippet file for javascript and edit it directly. It can be found here on a Mac, probably similarly located on Windows. Heads up it has been minified.

```
 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/javascript/snippets/javascript.code-snippets
```

If you want to just copy my own edited version of the snippet I've pasted it below.

```
{"define module":{"prefix":"define","body":["define([","\t'require',","\t'${1:dependency}'","], function(require, ${2:factory}) {","\t'use strict'","\t$0","})"],"description":"define module"},"For Loop":{"prefix":"for","body":["for (let ${1:index} = 0; ${1:index} < ${2:array}.length; ${1:index}++) {","\tconst ${3:element} = ${2:array}[${1:index}];","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}"],"description":"For Loop"},"For-Each Loop":{"prefix":"foreach","body":["${1:array}.forEach(${2:element} => {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","})"],"description":"For-Each Loop"},"For-In Loop":{"prefix":"forin","body":["for (const ${1:key} in ${2:object}) {","\tif (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(${2:object}, ${1:key})) {","\t\tconst ${3:element} = ${2:object}[${1:key}]","\t\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","\t}","}"],"description":"For-In Loop"},"For-Of Loop":{"prefix":"forof","body":["for (const ${1:iterator} of ${2:object}) {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}"],"description":"For-Of Loop"},"Function Statement":{"prefix":"function","body":["function ${1:name}(${2:params}) {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}"],"description":"Function Statement"},"If Statement":{"prefix":"if","body":["if (${1:condition}) {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}"],"description":"If Statement"},"If-Else Statement":{"prefix":"ifelse","body":["if (${1:condition}) {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","} else {","\t","}"],"description":"If-Else Statement"},"New Statement":{"prefix":"new","body":["const ${1:name} = new ${2:type}(${3:arguments})$0"],"description":"New Statement"},"Switch Statement":{"prefix":"switch","body":["switch (${1:key}) {","\tcase ${2:value}:","\t\t$0","\t\tbreak","","\tdefault:","\t\tbreak","}"],"description":"Switch Statement"},"While Statement":{"prefix":"while","body":["while (${1:condition}) {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}"],"description":"While Statement"},"Do-While Statement":{"prefix":"dowhile","body":["do {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","} while (${1:condition})"],"description":"Do-While Statement"},"Try-Catch Statement":{"prefix":"trycatch","body":["try {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","} catch (${1:error}) {","\t","}"],"description":"Try-Catch Statement"},"Set Timeout Function":{"prefix":"settimeout","body":["setTimeout(() => {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}, ${1:timeout})"],"description":"Set Timeout Function"},"Set Interval Function":{"prefix":"setinterval","body":["setInterval(() => {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","}, ${1:interval})"],"description":"Set Interval Function"},"Import Statement":{"prefix":"import","body":["import { $0 } from \"${1:module}\""],"description":"Import external module"},"Region Start":{"prefix":"#region","body":["//#region $0"],"description":"Folding Region Start"},"Region End":{"prefix":"#endregion","body":["//#endregion"],"description":"Folding Region End"},"Log to the console":{"prefix":"log","body":["console.log($1)"],"description":"Log to the console"},"Log warning to console":{"prefix":"warn","body":["console.warn($1)"],"description":"Log warning to the console"},"Log error to console":{"prefix":"error","body":["console.error($1)"],"description":"Log error to the console"},"new Promise":{"prefix":"newpromise","body":["new Promise((resolve, reject) => {","\t$TM_SELECTED_TEXT$0","})"],"description":"Create a new Promise"}}
```